# How to get the IP address for a certain node in Contiki RPL classic?

Tags: ip, contiki, cooja

I would like to get the IP address for the mote. Not the IP for a parent or a neighbor but the IP for the current mote. I'm using Contiki 3.0 and working on RPL classic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the functions `uip_ds6_get_global` and `uip_ds6_get_link_local` to get the global IPv6 address and the link-local IPv6 address of the node, respectively.

Usage example:

```
uip_ds6_addr_t *addr;
addr = uip_ds6_get_global(ADDR_PREFERRED);
```

The return value is either `NULL` or a pointer to an address state structure `uip_ds6_addr_t`. The `ipaddr` member of that structure contains the actual IPv6 address.

The argument of the function is a filter on the state of the IPv6 address. It can be one of:

```
ADDR_TENTATIVE
ADDR_PREFERRED
ADDR_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried ADDR_PREFERRED and it's giving me an IP address that ends with zeros 100:aaaa::c30c:0:0. The other two arguments give me NULL IP. This is part of my code: 
     uip_ds6_addr_t *addr;
     addr = uip_ds6_get_global(ADDR_PREFERRED);
     PRINTF("Mote IP:");
     PRINT6ADDR(addr);
     PRINTF("\n");

Comment: My guess is that you interpret the `uip_ds6_addr_t` structure as IPv6 address. You should look at the `ipaddr` member in that structure instead, which is of type `uip_ipaddr_t`.

Comment: Thank you very much you are right it is working now.

Comment: What `uip_ds6_get_global()` returns is an Addr Structure, not an addr. To get the IPv6 Global addr out of it use: `&unicastAddrStructure->ipaddr`

Comment: I tried the code above. This is my code: uip_ds6_addr_t *ipaddr; 
ipaddr = uip_ds6_get_global(ADDR_PREFERRED); 
PRINTF("Current IPadress:"); 
PRINT6ADDR(ipaddr);  I am getting 0:0 at the end